# Calculate distance between two lat long points in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, geometry, geocoding, oracle-spatial

I'm trying to calculate the distance between two lat long points in Oracle using SDO_GEOM Package.
Most of the solutions I read on the internet suggests below query:

```
select sdo_geom.sdo_distance(
  sdo_geometry(2001, 4326, sdo_point_type(40.0, 10.0, null), null, null),
  sdo_geometry(2001, 4326, sdo_point_type(40.0, 11.0, null), null, null),
  0.01,
  'unit=KM'
) as distance
from dual;
```

However, when I use an online tool to validate the result, it seems to be incorrect:

Try (40,10), (40,11) on:

[http://www.meridianoutpost.com/resources/etools/calculators/calculator-latitude-longitude-distance.php](http://www.meridianoutpost.com/resources/etools/calculators/calculator-latitude-longitude-distance.php?)

Any idea why the distance calculation is incorrect even if I'm using a geographic coordinate system (4326) in the query?

Comment: are you sure you're not using longitude and latitude in place of each other?

Comment: It works like a charm when I swap longitude and latitude! Appreciate all your responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select sdo_geom.sdo_distance(
  sdo_geometry(2001, 4326, sdo_point_type(40.0, 10.0, null), null, null),
  sdo_geometry(2001, 4326, sdo_point_type(40.0, 11.0, null), null, null),
  0.01,
  'unit=KM'
) as distance
from dual;

DISTANCE
----------
110.611186
```

The Oracle calculation returns **110.611186 km**

The one on your site returns **111.19 km** so a difference of **580 m**. That difference is because your online calculator uses simple math assuming a **spherical** earth, whereas Oracle use the proper **ellipsoidal** shape of the earth (the WGS84 ellipsoid).

You can see the difference on https://www.fai.org/page/world-distance-calculator If you choose the **WGS84** earth model (the WGS84 ellipsoid) then you get the same result as Oracle (110.611186562098). If you change it to **FAI Sphere** then you get 111.19492643325476, the same as your comparator.

The correct distance is 110.611 km. Whether computing it with 580 m off is important depends on your application. If you measure short distances (like a km or less), the error is negligible. But for long distance it can be significant. Here it would mean missing a target by 1/2 km!

It does show the importance of using the correct earth model for those computations.

**EDIT:** And the Oracle representation (and pretty much all GIS tools) is **longitude, latitude**. If you swap the numbers, then you will get very different results.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in swaping the longitude and latitude

Here is an example calculation the distance of the Central Park and Broadway

```
select sdo_geom.sdo_distance(         --  longitude,  Latitude 
  sdo_geometry(2001, 4326, sdo_point_type(-73.968285, 40.785091, null), null, null),
  sdo_geometry(2001, 4326, sdo_point_type(-73.974709, 40.790886, null), null, null),
  0.01,
  'unit=KM'
) as distance
from dual;
```

which return

```
0,841504644128136
```

The link you mentioned gives (provided correct input) comparable result

```
 From: (40°47'6.3276000000001"N -73°58'5.826"E) To: (40°47'27.1896"N -73°58'28.9524"E)
0.52 miles / 0.84 kilometers / 0.45 nautical miles
```